# Java Vertx WebClient is not printing log from onSuccess, onFailure, onComplete method but receiving response

Tags: webclient, vertx-verticle, vert.x-webclient

I am trying to perform a http call using Java vertx. Below is my sample code which I am using to perform a http post call. After executing this code, I can receive the response but log messages which is written inside onsuccess or onFailure(when failure occur) or onComplete methods are not printing. Kindly help me to rectify the issue here.

---

> WebClient httpClient; VertxOptions vertxOption = new VertxOptions()
> .setBlockedThreadCheckInterval(config.getBlockedThreadCheckInterval())
> .setBlockedThreadCheckIntervalUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
> .setMaxEventLoopExecuteTime(config.getMaxEventLoopExecutionTime())
> .setMaxEventLoopExecuteTimeUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
> .setWarningExceptionTime(config.getWarningExecutionTime())
> .setWarningExceptionTimeUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
> .setMaxWorkerExecuteTime(config.getMaxWorkerExecutionTime())
> .setMaxWorkerExecuteTimeUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS);
> //.setWorkerPoolSize(config.getPoolSize());
>
> ```
>       WebClientOptions options = new WebClientOptions();          options
>           .setName(config.getVertxName())
>           .setConnectTimeout(config.getHttpConnectionTimeout() * 1000)
>           .setTrustAll(config.isHttpTrustAll())
>           .setKeepAlive(config.isHttpKeepAlive())
>               .setIdleTimeout(config.getHttpConnectionTimeout())
>               .setHttp2KeepAliveTimeout(config.getHttpConnectionTimeout())
>               .setMaxPoolSize(config.getPoolSize());
>           Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx(vertxOption)
>                   .exceptionHandler(Throwable::printStackTrace);
>
>       try{
>           httpClient = WebClient.create(vertx, options);
>
>       } catch (Exception e) {
>           log.error("Error while starting vertx client {0} ",e.getCause());
>
>       } httpClient
>           .postAbs("http://localhost:8080/traveldetails/enquery")
>           .expect(ResponsePredicate.SC_SUCCESS)           .as(BodyCodec.pipe(new KryoStreamWriter<>(consumer, latch)))            .sendBuffer(buffer)
>       .onSuccess(res->{
>           future.complete("Future Complete");
>           log.info("success response....................");           })          .onFailure(frc->{
>           log.error("failure response");
>           log.error("Error : {}", frc.getCause());
>           future.completeExceptionally(new Throwable("Error occur in vertx"));
>
>       }).onComplete(asyncResult ->{
>           System.out.println("Status value "+asyncResult.result().statusCode());
>           if(asyncResult.succeeded())
>               log.info("On Complete............................ and status code {}", asyncResult.result().statusCode());
>           else
>               log.error("Failed to get complete the request {} ", asyncResult.result().statusCode());
>
>           latch.countDown();          });
> ```

---